# ogr2ogr selecting features by location

Tags: shapefile, sql, geometry, ogr2ogr, sqlite

I'm trying select features from one shapefile that contains features from another shapefile. However when I run the command I get an error " no such column geometry" Both shapefiles are working normally.
Any ideas what could be the issue? 
Here is my command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" selection_polygon.shp shapefile_polygon.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT * FROM shapefile_polygon polygon, 'shapefile_point.shp'.shapefile_point point WHERE ST_Contains(polygon.geometry, point.geometry)
```

Comment: Have you tried with SQLite SQL dialect?

Comment: Please, include the output for `ogrinfo -so -dialect sqlite -sql "select * from shapefile_polygon" shapefile_polygon.shp` and `ogrinfo -so -dialect sqlite -sql "select * from shapefile_point" shapefile_point.shp`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be very close. I believe the remaining issue is to include double quotes and escape them correctly to build and pass "delimited"."identifiers" correctly to GDAL and SQLite/SpatiaLite.  This works for me on Windows.

```
ogrinfo -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT * FROM polygon polygon, \"point.shp\".\"point\" point WHERE ST_Contains(\"polygon\".\"geometry\", \"point\".\"geometry\")" polygon.shp
INFO: Open of `polygon.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry (GEOMETRY): Polygon
Geometry (GEOMETRY): Point
Feature Count: 1
Extent (GEOMETRY): (300.000000, 400.000000) - (360.000000, 460.000000)
Extent (GEOMETRY): (320.000000, 420.000000) - (320.000000, 420.000000)
SRS WKT (GEOMETRY):
(unknown)
SRS WKT (GEOMETRY):
(unknown)
Geometry Column 1 = GEOMETRY
Geometry Column 2 = GEOMETRY
poly_attr: String (0.0)
point_attr: String (0.0)
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  poly_attr (String) = poly_1
  point_attr (String) = point_1
  GEOMETRY = POLYGON ((300 400,300 460,360 460,360 400,300 400))
  GEOMETRY = POINT (320 420)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to replace the * in your code with "polygon.Geometry, polygon.id" and see if there is any change?

The following code should run and create new file with the polygons that contain at least one of your points that will be named 'selection.shp'.

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" selection.shp shp_poly.shp -dialect sqlite -sql SELECT polygon.Geometry, polygon.id FROM shp_poly polygon, 'shp_point.shp'.shp_point point WHERE ST_Contains(polygon.geometry, point.geometry)
```